# I am having trouble copy pasting specific amount of cells and pasting them onto another

Tags: vba, excel

as the title says i want to do something like this.
Below i have an image of some data. It always consists of 24 rows.
Now i want to select each uneven one and paste it below the first column. I want to do the same with the second one as well. so for example i would want to select the cells with values under the D column and paste it under B starting from 26, then select the cells in F column and paste them below the ones i added in the previous step.  Similar to that i want to do the same with the C column. So E would paste under C, G after and so forth...

I am a first timer in visual basic excel and tried doing something like this but i get a sub or function not defined error, and i think my logic is flawed. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

this is my code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
j = 26
Dim target As Integer
target = 2

For k = 2 To 10
    For i = 2 To 25
        Cell(i, Column(k)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cell(j, Column(target)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    k = k + 1
Next k

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write cell and not cells, and next K doing the same function of K= k+1
the correct code si :

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
j = 26
Dim target As Integer
target = 2

For k = 2 To 3
    For i = 2 To 26
        Cells(i, k).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cells(j, target).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        j = j + 1
    Next i
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i noticed that while looking again at my code. But since this is the answer to my question im marking it as solved. Thanks!